# Why Jmeter Average Time not matching properly ?

Tags: time, jmeter, average

When I'm trying to execute  my test plan in jmeter for 10,50,100... virtual users with ram up period 30 sec and Loop count is 1. I'm not getting Average response time exactly when I calculated with Average Time=(Min Time+ Max Time)/2.
 Please check my attached image for differences in Average time[image]

Can anyone suggest me please how we need to understand this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: average time is not `(min + max)/2`. consider sequence such as `1 1 1 1000`

Comment: Thank You Ymonad for your reply but it is bit difficult right  for calculating Average (for 100,200,300..Thread Users)while execution.Can you please let me know if you have another way for understanding this calculation.

Comment: See this thread: [How to analyze a JMeter summary report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143401/how-to-analyze-a-jmeter-summary-report/38109414#38109414)

Answer (score 1):

**Average:** This is the Average elapsed time of a set of results. It is the **arithmetic mean** of all the samples **response time**.

The following equation show how the **Average value (μ)** is calculated:

> μ = 1/n * Σi=1…n xi

An important thing to understand is that the **mean value** can be very misleading as it does not show you **how close (or far)** your values are **from the average**.The main thing you should focus on is **"Standard Deviation"**.

The standard deviation (σ) measures the **mean distance of the values to their average (μ)**. In other words, it gives us a good idea of the **dispersion or variability** of the measures to their **mean value**.

The following equation show how the **standard deviation (σ)** is calculated:

> σ = 1/n * √ Σi=1…n (xi-μ)2

So interpreting the standard deviation is wise as mean value could be the same for the different response time of the samples! If the deviation value is **low compared to the mean value**, it will indicate you that your **measures are not dispersed (or mostly close to the mean value)** and that the **mean value is significant**.

**Min** - The **lowest elapsed time**(response time) for the samples with the same label.

**Max** - The **longest elapsed time** (response time) for the samples with the same label.

For further detail you could go through [JMeter documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report) and [this blog](https://nico.vahlas.eu/2010/03/30/some-thoughts-on-stress-testing-web-applications-with-jmeter-part-2/). It will really help you to understand the concept.